# Broken mount point with crazy status

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, sshfs

I used to mount via `sshfs` onto this mount point named `vismac` on a RedHat linux.

But something is broken, and `ls -l` results in the following mess of question marks and dashes:

```
drwxrwxr-x  9 user_me grp_me   4096 Jan 20 11:43 temp
?---------  ? ?       ?           ?            ? vismac
```

I have no clue what's going on. Any ideas?

`mount` shows:

```
sshfs#vismac.my.domain.com: on /home/memming/vismac type fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,max_read=65536,user=memming)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, `sshfs` must have choked. I forced with `sudo umount` and it's all fine now.